# Lifetime parameters in trait declarations

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am hoping to make a little more progress in my understanding of lifetimes and so I'm trying to figure this out. What am I telling the compiler when I write this?

```rs
trait MyTrait<'a> {
    fn foo(&'a self) -> &'a str;
}
```

and how is it different from when I write this?

```rs
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str;
}
```

(the difference syntactically is that I moved the declaration of the `<'a>` lifetime to the method instead of the trait)

I had thought that in both cases I was simply declaring a lifetime parameter for use in the method signature, but that seems to be very incorrect because the first block produces unexpected error messages.

What I'm trying to express is "the `str` returned from `foo()` should have the same lifetime as the object implementing `MyTrait`". And to that end the second block seems to be the right way to say it. I'm also aware that in this case I can just leave out all the lifetime annotations and just let the compiler infer them, but part of the exercise I'm going through is to try to use explicit lifetime parameters everywhere to test my knowledge of what they mean.

The context where this came up is illustrated in this code, where the first syntax above produces errors, but the second one doesn't:

```rs
trait MyTrait<'a> {
    fn borrow_contents(&'a self) -> &'a str;
}

struct Foo {
    contents: String,
}

impl<'a> MyTrait<'a> for Foo {
    fn borrow_contents(&'a self) -> &'a str {
        &self.contents
    }
}

fn main() {
    let boxed_trait_object: Box<dyn MyTrait> = Box::new(Foo {
        contents: "first".into(),
    });
    boxed_trait_object.borrow_contents(); // -> ERROR: borrowed value does not live long enough...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the lifetime parameter with a type parameter; is it easier for you to understand now?

```rust
trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn foo(v: T);
}
// Versus:
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo<T>(v: T);
}
```

In this first snippet, *the trait* contains the (lifetime or type) parameter. That means the *implementor* is choosing what the parameter will be. A specific type can have multiple implementations for different parameters (coming from a single generic `impl` blocks or from multiple distinct `impl` blocks), but each implementation defines its own `foo()`, that takes its specified `T` (or the lifetime parameter). For example, you can implement `MyTrait<u32> for Foo` and `MyTrait<u64> for Foo`, with different logic for `foo()`.

With the second snippet, *the method* defines the parameter. That means *the caller of the method* is choosing what the parameter will be. The method defines a uniform interface and implementation that works with *all* types (or lifetimes) (satisfying on the constraints specified), and the caller chooses what type to put instead of `T`.

Those ways of declaring *sometimes* lead to the same result, because just like `fn foo<T>()` defines a uniform interface and implementation, we can define a generic impl `impl<T> MyTrait<T> for Foo`, and that will also force a uniform interface and implementation. However, the discrepancies reveal themselves when we are forced into matching a specific implementation of the trait. Usually we are allowed in each call to call a different implementation, but in the following cases we are forced to pick *one* implementation only:

- With generic code. Since Rust have no higher-ranked type bounds (`for<T>`), we cannot say we take "a type that implements `MyTrait<T>` for any `T` (`U: for<T> MyTrait<T>`), so we are forced to pick *one* concrete implementation. That means we can call `foo()` in the second snippet with any type, since *inside one implementation* `foo()` can take many types, but we are forced to call `foo()` in the first snippet with only one type, the type we put in the trait bounds.
- Default method implementations. This is similar to generic code in that inside default method bodies the trait is assumed to be implemented for `Self` *with the same generic parameters*, but not others. So we can call the second snippet with any type (because that is the interface we defined), but the first snippet only with the same `T` as in implementing type, i.e. the `T` declared in the trait.

Your example also fails because of this. By specifying `dyn MyTrait`, you actually say `dyn MyTrait<'_>`, which means again a *specific* lifetime and therefore a *specific* implementation.

These concerns apply more to type parameters and less to lifetime parameters because we have HRTB. Your example can also be fixed with them:

```rust
fn main() {
    let boxed_trait_object: Box<dyn for<'a> MyTrait<'a>> = Box::new(Foo {
        contents: "first".into(),
    });
    boxed_trait_object.borrow_contents();
}
```

Still, it is less convenient, and therefore you should prefer specifying the parameters on the method when you can.

It seems the second snippet is always more general, so why we have the first? It is useful in the following cases:

- Object safety. This does not apply to lifetime parameters, but with type parameters, the first snippet is object-safe but the second is not.
- Sometimes, we actually *cannot* implement the trait for any type/lifetime. This is when the first form is useful. For example:

```rust
struct Foo<T>(T);

trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> &T;
}

impl<T> MyTrait<T> for Foo<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> &T { &self.0 }
}
```

Here, we *cannot* implement `foo()` for any type, because we only have a single `T` we can hand (you may be confused because this is a generic implementation, for any `T`; but for each concrete `Foo<T>`, we only have one `T` we can hand).

Or with lifetimes, perhaps the type contain a reference with some specific lifetime and so cannot implement the trait with any lifetime. For example:

```rust
struct Foo<'a>(&'a u32);

trait MyTrait<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> &'a u32;
}

impl<'a> MyTrait<'a> for Foo<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> &'a u32 { self.0 }
}
```

Again, here we cannot give any lifetime, only what we have.

Still, the more common case (especially with lifetimes) is to put the parameter on the method, and this is indeed the default: if you omit the lifetime, the elided lifetime will become a hidden parameter on the method. This:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self) -> &str;
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str;
}
```

Not this:

```rust
trait MyTrait<'a> {
    fn foo(&'a self) -> &'a str;
}
```